# Expanding multiple divs independently based on Boolean variable value

Tags: html, angular

I have a list of `mat-card` components that are individually expanded on clicking a button within each card. So far the Boolean variable has been defined within the HTML code itself rather than in the Angular .ts file, however I am wanting to transition this to use a Boolean in the .ts file.

I have attempted to assign a simple Boolean, however I now find that all of the cards expand at the same time...

I know what is wrong, but I cannot think about the way in which to fix it :-/

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ts-variable-not-local)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your cards are created with an ngFor directive from an array, the expanded data should be stored in an array too!

.ts

```
thisExpands = [];
```

.html

```
[ngClass]="{expanded: thisExpands[x]}"

(click)="thisExpands[x] = !thisExpands[x]"
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ts-variable-not-local-xashud?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)